# Do not use 'yet' to say that something is continuing to happen

Tags: grammar

> Do not use '*yet*' to say something is continuing to happen
>
> *He **still** doesn't understand. Brian's toe is **still** badly swollen.*
>
> (Collins Cobuild Usage 2004)

However

> [3. in the time still remaining; before all is done: *There is **yet**
> time*.](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/yet)

Is then *there is **yet** time* not grammatical?

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly grammatical, but rather old-fashioned and literary. As Collins Cobuild is intended for learners, it advises against using *yet* for *still.*

Comment: I saw a man fall from a cliff yesterday; he screamed horribly. I hear him yet.